# Public IP to VM in esxi

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

So I had proxmox installed but boss decided to install vmware esxi in ovh vps so this is the scenario. I have a server which has esxi and I have purchased a bunch of Ips from OVH since I want to have public IPs for VMs in the esxi host. So in Proxmox I had something like network configuration for routed network.

By far what I have done is

```
Created a VM then placed the interface of the VM in switch0 and management network

The IP is as given by OVH 

IP: 101.96.187.49
gateway: 101.22.12.3  [vmware esxi host]
DNS: 8.8.8.8
|
Ip block provided by OVH: 101.96.187.48/29
 

After this I can ping the gateway
```

Since I cannot use bridge interface as OVH restricts multi mac from its interface. So is there a way like routed network for esxi kindly assist

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it !!

I had to add mac of the interface that was carrying the IP. In the ovh console

More over I matched
101.96.187.49  ====> 00:11:ee:aa:ww...
and so on

Then a little modification in the configuration

```
IP: 101.96.187.49

gateway: 101.96.187.54  [Last IP of the network]

DNS: 8.8.8.8
```

Thank you